# How are the default keyboard interactions of QtQuick Controls 2 specified?

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

The controls in QtQuick.Controls 2 have some keyboard responses by default.

For example, the `ComboBox` will change selection in response to the up & down keys, and the box' `Popup` will open if the user presses spacebar. I haven't been able to find where this behavior was specified, and I need to change it.

At the moment, I need the return key to do what the spacebar is doing. But of course being able to customize these key interactions is generally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to configure Qt Quick Controls 2 to do all the actions everywhere with the return key, that it would do with the spacebar key. However, you can attach a [Keys](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html) handler and apply the desired actions yourself:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    Keys.onReturnPressed: comboBox.popup.open()
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this was also part of the question: *Can you disable the default behavior?* So, what happens, if the `space bar` is doing something, but I want it to do something else?

Comment: Yes, the `Keys` attached property can be configured to handle key events before or after the item it is attached to. This makes it possible to intercept events in order to override an item's default behavior, or act as a fallback for keys not handled by the item. See [Key Handling Priorities](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#key-handling-priorities) for more details.

Comment: I wound up digging through Qt source and patching it (I was already building Qt from patched source for an embedded target) but this is a more generally applicable answer, missing only an answer to the question "how do I know what all the default key behavior is?" (from source, I see that by default return will close but not open a popup, which I hadn't discovered by experiment)